# cin as a conditional in a while loop?

Tags: c++, cin

A bit new to C++ here. Is it possible to do something like the following?

```
int temp;
while(cin >> temp != -9999){//Do something with temp}
```

I can't get that exact code to work, but I feel like something such as that should be possible.

**Edit**
Tried the following as well:

```
while(cin.getline(temp) != -9999){//Do something with temp}
```

Still nothing. Does `getline()` only work with strings?

Comment: `while(std::cin >> temp && temp != -9999)`

Comment: the >> operator returns a reference to the input stream (in this case standard input). Your piece of code is in effect comparing that reference to a stream against the value -9999. Rapptz solves that for you.

Comment: @user2280716 Short circuiting is never applied in reverse order.  It's well defined, left to right.

Comment: `getline` *does* only work with strings, but you should be using `std::getline`, not `std::cin.getline`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does:

```
while (std::cin >> temp && temp != -9999)
```

However, operator precedence in C++ is annoying, so I would use:

```
while (std::cin >> temp) {
    if (temp == -9999)
        break;
```

The reasoning is that `std::cin` is a stream. As such, reading from it returns the stream so you can do things like:

```
std::cin >> temp >> temp2;
```

Comment: Didn't even think about using `&&`. Makes sense though!